# redirect into subdirectory AND out of subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, infinite-loop

i have a mod_rewrite redirection problem i cannot figure out.

all requests from a specific domain get "silently" rewritten into a designated subdirectory. e.g. `www.mydomain.net/hello.html` retrieves the file in `/net/hello.html`. the following .htaccess *(placed in my hosting root)* achieves this perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 # <-- i will need this later. read to the end of the post.
RewriteRule .* - [L]
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.net$
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/net.*$
rewriteRule (.*) /net/$1 [L]
```

however, direct URLs into this directory however should visibly redirect with a 301 to the URL *without* that subdirectory. e.g. `www.mydomain.net/net/hello.html` should redirect to `www.mydomain.net/hello.html` (which than still retrieves the file in `/net/hello.html`). my .htacces file for this *(placed in `/net`)* unfortunately doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

i get an infinitive redirect loop despite the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` block in the root .htaccess file... so what's wrong?

btw, i have to use mod_rewrite, because the site is externaly hosted and i have no access to the apache configs.

many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the [HTTP request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) in *THE_REQUEST* instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /net[/? ]
RewriteRule ^net($|/(.*)) /$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks gumbo! using THE_REQUEST circumvents the loop.

however, the RewriteRule line i had to change to "RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]", because the .htaccess file is executed from the subdir "net".